# The problem with SCNView and processor loading in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, nsview, macos-mojave, scnscene

I have a problem with Mojave and SCNView in my macOS program. But, I have also tested the simplest project and found the same problem !

So, if we start new macOS project with xib file, not storyboard, and put the NSTabView (with two TabView) in the window. Then when we place the SCNView in the TabView which is not active at start of the program what we will have after building and start program is 100% processor load. And, it stays 100% till we open the TabView with SCNView, then the processor load is dropping to zero.

This should not be like this, this simplest project has no custom code, just loading the Views!

Nothing like this was seen in previous macOS